# No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I'm getting this error when trying to run `react-native run-android`:

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

I also get:

> AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

I've looked around StackOverflow and I have seen some people get similar issues and they solved it with making sure their build version which also matches the `appcompat` version in the build.grade file. However, this doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I have:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    ...
}
...
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and got it solved by changing the build tool version to 25.0.0 and target version to 25. I am using Android studio 2.3.

Hope it might help you.

Comment: Is there a solution for cordova / phonegap projects which have the same problem? Thanks