# React Native, Android: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'

Tags: android, react-native

I'm building an Android app using React Native `0.43.4`.

After running `react-native run-android`, I get the following errors:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.


:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I've seen a similar issue caused by the compile SDK version not matching the build tools version:

[Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144415/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

However, if you look at my build.gradle, you'll see that they do match:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-navigation')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Lastly, I've installed the Android SDK using Android studio. When I type `android list target` I get the following:

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Google APIs
     Based on Android 6.0 (API level 23)
     Libraries:
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
----------
id: 2 or "android-23"
     Name: Android API 23
     Type: Platform
     API level: 23
     Revision: 3
----------
id: 3 or "android-24"
     Name: Android API 24
     Type: Platform
     API level: 24
     Revision: 2
----------
id: 4 or "android-25"
     Name: Android API 25
     Type: Platform
     API level: 25
     Revision: 3
----------
id: 5 or "android-26"
     Name: Android API 26
     Type: Platform
     API level: 26
     Revision: 1
```

I'd love any help I can get!

Comment: Have u tried this ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636421/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-androidtextappearance-material-w?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: alright, i once had this problem and all i can remember right now was that it was react-native-fbsdk that was causing the problem so i had to edit the node modules and it worked. are you using react-native-fbsdk ?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue.

If you do use the react-native-fbsdk, please check the question and answers here: [Facebook Sdk Android Error Building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190829/facebook-sdk-android-error-building)

For me, I solved this problem by simply changing the compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion in /android/app/build.gradle to 25 and 25.0.1.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion “25.0.1”
```